# Segmentation fault in C on Mac, direct copy from a tutorial

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

I've started learning C and pointers and I've been working on tutorials on the internet. I assume that the code should work as it is in a tutorial, and it seems right to me, but I get a segmentation error. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float fl = 3.14;
    unsigned int addr = (unsigned int) &fl;
    printf("fl's address=%u\n", addr);
    printf("addr's contents = %.2f\n", * (float*) addr);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The error that I get is

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans       
6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33:  1626     
Segmentation fault      sh "${SHFILE}"
```

Does this have to do with me using a Mac or is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks a lot,
Niek

Comment: What tools are you using to compile this? This should work fine if you're just using GCC at the terminal.

Comment: @Chris I used both NetBeans and -gcc, both didn't work. But sampblebias example worked so I'm going to build on that.

Comment: Are you using Snow Leopard by chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float fl = 3.14;
    float *addr = &fl;
    printf("fl's address=%p\n", addr);
    printf("addr's contents = %.2f\n", *addr);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `uintptr_t` would also work (with a cast), since it's guaranteed to be large enough to store pointer types. The format string would be `printf("fl's address=%" PRIuPTR "\n", addr)`

Comment: @samplebias, this is nit picking, but to be completely conforming you should cast the pointer to `void*` when you pass it to `printf`. `gcc`, e.g, would warn you.

Comment: @Jens - I wish I could give you reputation for "the most nit-picking-est comment ever."

Comment: @Chris awesome. @Jens I see your point, but I compiled with -Wall with gcc on Mac and Linux, no warnings.

Comment: @samplebias - Does `-Wextra` help?

Comment: @Chris - just warns about "unused argc, argv".

Comment: @Chris, @samplebias, I was sure it would warn you... but seemingly it doesn't. Well, in any case, on not so common architectures with different pointer type widths this would be necessary. Pointers are not automatically promoted to `void*` when passed through a va-arg function.

Comment: @Jens, @samplebias - I looked through the list of warning flags GCC has, and I couldn't find anything to warn for this. Pity, since I can't imagine it being that difficult for GCC to check.

Answer (score 4):

That may be undefined behaviour. There's no guarantee that an `int` and a pointer can hold the same value, and you should not be casting between them. Use a `float*` instead.

C99 `6.3.2.3/5` and `/6` state:

> 5: An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> 6: Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

Comment: @Chris, technically that's an optional type per the standard, but probably available in any decent environment. Or you could just use `float*` to make your life simpler :-)

Comment: The `printf` format for pointers doesn't have much control with regards to output format.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the address space of pointer is not guaranteed to be the same as an int.  In fact, this code gives me the following compilation warnings using gcc on a Mac Pro:

test.c:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
test.c:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

and a seg fault as well.  I would consider samplebias' code.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be correct, compiling with MinGW GCC and running gives the following output:

```
fl's address=2293528
addr's contents = 3.14
```

Comment: When I use GCC to compile I get test.c:                             In function ‘main’:
test.c:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
test.c:11: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’. Do you know why yours can compile and mine can't?

Comment: OK, I don't even get this with `-Wall`... seems like a datatype size issue or a 32/64-bit problem then, I'm on a Windows 7 32-Bit system here.

Comment: @Beorn - Are you natively 64 bit? If so, that's probably the problem.

Comment: `-Wall` is a huge lie propagated by the gcc bods :-) It's not 'all' at all. You may find it pops up by adding `-Wextra` as well (but I'm not sure).

Comment: @paxdiablo: No, doesn't help either, but it's interesting to know and even better to read `gcc --help=warnings` - there are diamonds like "-Wall: Enable *most* warning messages" and several "This switch lacks documentation".

Answer (score 1):

yes under win7 + mingw32, the code compiles\executes corrrectly

```
fl's address=2293572
addr's contents = 3.14
```

i think it's problem with MacOS only

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of `int`. As @paxdiablo already said, there is no guarantee that an `int` is big enough to hold the same value as a pointer. Try `long long`instead, but be warned, the code stays in the *undefined behavior* corner.

Comment: No, never try to guess the type to convert a pointer to an integer, *if you have to*. `uintptr_t` is made for this. And if this doesn't exists on a platform this is a strong indication that you definitively shouldn't even try it.

Comment: @Jens - The conversion of a pointer to an integer is usually safe. It's the conversion back that (I believe) is causing the OP's segfault.

Comment: @Chris, the information loss is at the point of conversion to the integer type, usually. For me the segmentation fault is only a symptom, the cause is the loss of significant bytes.

Comment: @Jens - You can still get a usable integer out of it. The integer no longer describes a pointer type, but it's (usually, in practice) an okay operation in and of itself.

Comment: I myself would just use `void *` if I need a "typeless" pointer. I do not know where the OP's example comes from, but it uses an ordinary integral number type. I just explained why it does not work as expected, and how he can fix his segfault. The warning about UB should be enough.

Comment: @Chris, this is a sort of biased pseudo random generator, no? I can't come up with much other use for such a value.

Comment: @swegi - It's not UB to use `uintptr_t` (if it exists). It's not necessarily UB to use `long long` if it is big enough, but you can't really check whether it's big enough, and if it's not, _then_ it's UB. So saying "Try `long long` instead" is not (in my opinion) a good answer. UB behavior can be avoided altogether with `uintptr_t` - why recommend an inferior solution? @Jens - I can't either. Maybe it'd be a seed for a PRNG. Maybe you prefer to print pointers in other formats and don't care about the truncated digits (i.e. you're comparing array indices). I was mostly going on principle.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: You are right, using `uintptr_t` is superior when using C99. Unfortunately, C89 does not specify this type (afaik).